# Cocos2d Game Crashes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I used cocos2d 2.1 beta. When I run keep idle for few minutes then game crashes in same place every time. Please see attach image. How can I solve this crash.

Nothing much in game..simple background with few menu buttons.

[image]

Comment: did you try this on a device? Simulator crashes could be anything, including bad memory, corrupted drivers, ...

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, yes in simulator lots of time..in device got one crash once..not able to regenerate..so I thought same crash. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in simulator only, every time. Just run on a device..

Comment: That's because of debugging may be.